# combo box e input text

Tags: php, html, jquery, formulário

É o seguinte eu estou desenvolvendo um formulário,
queria que num dos campos do formulário aparece-se um input text e  select html,
e se a pessoa escolhesse o item do select com varias option's,
fosse enviado os dados digitados para a  base de dados com o item da option que foi selecionado com o os dados do input;
eu no formulário estou a ir buscar os valores por ID visto que sao 2 itens, continua a funcionar?
Como eu faria isso?

```html
<select id="inserir_dados">
  <option>Exemplo 1</option>
  <option>Exemplo 2</option>
  <option>Exemplo 3</option>
  <option>Exemplo 4</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="inserir_dados" placeholder="Caso nao exista"/>
```

Comment: Olá,  Shider. Coloque mais códigos relacionados ao que você pretende fazer, pois pela descrição em si eu não entendi nada. Forneça o maior número de informações possíveis para que sua pergunta não seja negativada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro não se deve usar o mesmo `id` em mais de 1 elemento. Isso é errado.

Você deveria atribuir nomes (`name`) diferentes no *combo* e no `input`, e colocar valores (`value`) em cada `option` da *combo*. São esses `value` que serão capturados no PHP de acordo com o `name`:

```
<select id="inserir_dados1" name="meu_nome">
  <option value="1">Exemplo 1</option>
  <option value="2">Exemplo 2</option>
  <option value="3">Exemplo 3</option>
  <option value="4">Exemplo 4</option>
</select>
<input name="meu_nome2" type="text" id="inserir_dados2" placeholder="Caso nao exista"/>
```

Ao submeter o formulário, no PHP você irá capturar o valor da *combo* e do `input` e definir o que será enviado ao banco de acordo com o valor de cada um pelo critério que você deseja (ex., se o valor da *combo* não for vazio ou do `input`):

```
<?php
    $meu_nome = $_POST['meu_nome']; // valor da combo
    $meu_nome2 = $_POST['meu_nome2']; // valor do input
?>
```

Digamos que se no `input` foi enviado algum valor e você queira ignorar o valor da *combo*:

```
<?php
    $meu_nome = $_POST['meu_nome']; // valor da combo
    $meu_nome2 = $_POST['meu_nome2']; // valor do input

    if(!empty($meu_nome2)){
       $valor_que_vai_pro_banco = $meu_nome2;
    }else if(!empty($meu_nome)){
       $valor_que_vai_pro_banco = $meu_nome;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Dvd o isset não deveria ser nos _POST? pois se não ele só servirá para checar se é NULL, ao invés de da key existir na superglobal.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimentoP. Mudei pra `empty`... coloquei só uma parte para pegar o valor. A validação do formulário imagino que ele deve ter.

Comment: sim penso que seja isso vou tentar por em pratica!!

Comment: e sim eu vou buscar os valores dos inputs e assim pelo metodo POST

Comment: @Shider fico contente em ter ajudado. Obrigado!

Comment: @dvd Obrigado eu!